# React.js - Controlled input toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a string of numbers and add commas to create a more readable format for a long number. Normally I'd use `toLocaleString()` but it's not working as expected with a controlled input.

In my code I'm doing:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    const parseNumber = parseInt(event.target.value);
    const toLocale = parseNumber.toLocaleString();
    this.setState({ value: toLocale });
  }
```

It's resetting the field after 3 numbers are entered - any ideas?

https://codesandbox.io/s/91q75k22mo

Comment: I think this is like an issue of react. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6368

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working solution - in your handleChange function, change this:

```
const toNumber = Number(event.target.value);
```

to this:

```
const toNumber = Number(event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

The reason it wasn't working was because it was creating a `Number` based on the input value, which isn't a plain number but a formatted string. Hence it contains non-digit characters. The above just removes the non-digit characters (though now you know the issue there are other ways you could solve it).

Comment: That's perfect, working as expected. Good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormattedNumber` from `react-intl`. The documentation is available here: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#number-formatting-components

A sample:

```
<IntlProvider locale='en'>
  <FormattedNumber value={examples.negativeNumber} />
</IntlProvider>
```

Comment: This could work alright, but I'd prefer a solution without any extra components if possible.

Comment: If you do this, does it work better? `this.setState({ value: parseNumber.toLocaleString() });`

Comment: Nope, but answer posted above.